# how to fit in smtplib in a class

Tags: python, smtp

i've tried calling stmplib.login in a function. I've looked around but not found much a way to fit it in a class. sendmail is being called in three places so need to initialize smtplib.smtp in one place and call it in different functions.

Honestly, I like the simplicity with which author (http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex43.html) of this link has explained how to go about making classes. I get it. Before, i go on further i hit an error on line

```
self.smtpaccess.login(self.MAILUSER, self.MAILPASSWORD)
```

which says

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'login'`

Am i thinking correct in terms of object oriented'ness

```
class outLook(object):
    def __init__(self,ms,mpr,mu,mps):
        self.smtpaccess = ""
        self.MAILSERVER = ms
        self.MAILPORT = mpr
        self.MAILUSER = mu
        self.MAILPASSWORD = mps

    def authenticate(self):
        try:
            self.smtpaccess = smtplib.SMTP(self.MAILSERVER , self.MAILPORT)
            self.smtpaccess.starttls()
            self.smtpaccess.ehlo()
        except smtplib.socket.gaierror:
            print 'smtplib.socket.gaierror'

    def outlookLogin(self):
        try:
            self.smtpaccess.login(self.MAILUSER, self.MAILPASSWORD)
        except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
            print 'SMTPAuthenticationError'

    def sendMailToProducer(self):
        pass

    def sendMailToArtist(self,name):
        pass

outLookResult = outLook('smtp.office365.com',nnn,'xxxxxxxxsupport@xxxxxxxxxx.in','xxxxnnnnn')
outLookResult.outlookLogin()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initially set

```
 self.smtpaccess = ""
```

making it the string `""` hence the error,

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'login'

You intialise it properly in `authenticate`:

```
self.smtpaccess = smtplib.SMTP(self.MAILSERVER , self.MAILPORT)
```

Either call `authenticate` before `outlookLogin` or do that work in `__init__` so you don't forget to call it.

Comment: when i move self.smtpaccess = smtplib.SMTP(self.MAILSERVER , self.MAILPORT) in init(), it works. is it okay to call smtplib.SMTP inside of init()

Comment: That's ok, and sensible - then you won't forget.